# Build Procedure for dll of GnuMP library on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, porting

Can somebody let me know the process of building the gnuMP Libraries on Windows.
I required a DLL of gnuMP Library but the build system does't allow me to create the dll library for windows OS.
I have tried to build using the MinGW and Cygwin but dll is not created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. But I have managed to Build dll of GnuMP library on Windows

On windows systems ‘*-*-cygwin*’, ‘*-*-mingw*’ and ‘*-*-pw32*’ by default GMP builds only a static library, but a DLL can be built instead using

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared
```

Static and DLL libraries can't both be built, since certain export directives in gmp.h must be different.
A MINGW DLL build of GMP can be used with Microsoft C. Libtool doesn't install a .lib format import library, but it can be created with MS lib as follows, and copied to the install directory. Similarly for libmp and libgmpxx.

```
cd .libs
lib /def:libgmp-3.dll.def /out:libgmp-3.lib
```

MINGW uses the C runtime library ‘msvcrt.dll’ for I/O, so applications wanting to use the GMP I/O routines must be compiled with ‘cl /MD’ to do the same. If one of the other C runtime library choices provided by MS C is desired then the suggestion is to use the GMP string functions and confine I/O to the application.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Pradip. This information is really helpfull for me. and its works perfectly.